# Can I subscribe to multiple firebase documents based on an array?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My firebase database has a user profile collection, where all the documents are UIDs, each document has a field called subscriptions which is an array of strings, each string being other UIDs.

I have a second collection for host content, where each document contains fields such as imageurl and caption, essentially posts that user has made.

Is there any way I can use the streamprovider on the host content collection to only show the posts by the UID the current user has a subscription for?
[image]

Comment: In your subscription array, I see that you are hosting the user ID, is this what you want? Would it be better to add host content IDs (jWM8...K5C7) rather than user IDs?

Comment: A new user would subscribe/follow a host so I don't know how basing it off the host content ID would work as opposed to the useruid?

Comment: In your screenshot, the document id is the same as one it is in his subscriptions. So a user can subscribe to himself?

Comment: It would show their own content in the main feed by default yes

Answer (score 0):

There are no SQL-like joins in Firestore, so your only option here (without changing any data) is to add a new listener on each document in hostconent that matches what's in the profile.  There is no way to do this with a single query.

If you want to do this with a single query, you should have a field for each document in hostcontent that identifies which profile it's associated with.  Then you can make a single query using that field as a filter to find only the documents for a profile.

Comment: If you can point me towards a better solution I'd be grateful too, it was just the only way I could see of doing it initially.

Comment: My answer does contain my recommended course of action.

Comment: Thanks, still learning, how would I add a listener to match the subscriptions array? collection.where('useruid', arraycontainsany: List.of(UserData(uid: uid).subscriptions)) returns null and arraycontainsany would limit me to 10 subscriptions anyway?